# missing data in master-to-master replication with mysql instances

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I am using MySQL 8. I have two masters which are configured as master-master replication with the following configuration in my.cnf.
The configuration is identical, except server-id. It seemed to be working ok until I recently ran a spring boot with a lot of data.

I have a highest parent table, called 'products' table and there are 4 or 5 child tables which are referenced by products table through product_id foreign key.

I noticed that a small insert/update/delete on one master is reflected on another master table through replication.

I had to upload 2300 products into a product table. Each product has 3 or 4 more attributes (images and some options) which should be saved in 4 or 5 child tables.

I noticed that while it was inserting product data into products table and other child tables in one of masters db, i didn't see any replicated data in another master db. When I tested 50 products table, it worked ok.

I checked the log (/var/log/mysqldb.log) to see if there is any failure. I didn't see any.

So I am trying to figure out when the replication happens. Does it happen after the entire transaction is completed in java app side or does the replication happen whenever any change (by row) is made to the table?

It seems to me that transaction isn't committed until the loop in Java app ends. That's fine. Shouldn't the replication happen if the replication starts after the transaction? Or is there any misconfiguration in my.cnf?

Thanks.

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.

sql-mode=""


innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M
innodb_stats_on_metadata        = 0
innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64


key_buffer_size                 = 48M   # UPD
back_log                        = 512
thread_cache_size               = 100
thread_stack                    = 192K

interactive_timeout             = 180
wait_timeout                    = 180

# Buffer Settings
join_buffer_size                = 4M    # UPD
read_buffer_size                = 3M    # UPD
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 4M    # UPD
sort_buffer_size                = 4M    # UPD





default-storage-engine=InnoDB
max_user_connections=100
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
max_connect_errors              = 1000000


#
# Remove the leading "# " to disable binary logging
# Binary logging captures changes between backups and is enabled by
# default. It's default setting is log_bin=binlog
# disable_log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
#
# Remove leading # to revert to previous value for default_authentication_plugin,
# this will increase compatibility with older clients. For background, see:
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin

default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password


skip-name-resolve

port=3306

server-id               = 1


datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid







####### replication #########

log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = sampledb
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log.index
relay_log           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay_log_index     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
max_binlog_size     = 100M
log_slave_updates   = 1


slave_type_conversions=ALL_NON_LOSSY
```

Comment: What API were you using?  Did you check for errors immediately after each `INSERT`?

Comment: There was an error replicating quartz scheduler tables. I moved those tables to other db. since that, i haven't seen any error yet.. thx.